# Changing label in other view in swift

Tags: swift, viewcontroller, xcode6

I have a label in a second viewController in Swift, and I want change this between my firstViewController. I try this with prepareForSegue: also with ChildView and ParentView and accessing to label since parentView.. But I get error..
What is the correct form to can make this?

Try declared secondVIew:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
var v = View2Controller()
@IBAction func but(sender : AnyObject) {

    v.label2.text = "newText"    //Here get the error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
}
...


 class View2Controller: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var label2 : UILabel
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code and where you are getting error??

Comment: I have edited this with a try

Comment: I need make this, and I have never idea.. I get errors all time.. I think that there is any form. I get pass data between viewCOntroller in navigation bar but not in normal viewController, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The more code you provide the easier it is to get answers.

In your case, you are initializing a band new `View2Controller`. Since `label2` is an IBOutlet it expects data from a nib file. Since it didn't get any of this data, label2 is going to be nil hence why you get a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` crash.

You can access the root view controller of a navigation controller because navigation controllers are special in that they have their own stack and maintain their own view hierarchy. This is why you have to push and pop view controllers in a navigation controller. This also allows child controllers to maintain a reference to its parent controller.

The proper solution for your situation would be to use protocols. Otherwise give `View2Controller` a property and reference to `ViewController` then make changes to `ViewController` through that property.